# Generic Typescript function is not recognising object

Tags: typescript, generics

```
let p1 = {name: "steve", age: 5};

function   greet <T> (obj: T) {
  console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}, I am ${this.age} years old.`);
}

greet(p1);
```

Gives output

```
Hello, my name is undefined, I am undefined years old.
```

P1 is object. I am passing Object to Generic Greet function. Also, object has same properties that greet function needs to display output. Can anyone explain why am getting "undefined" to novice TS enthusiast, please?

Comment: I think you made a typo. It should be `obj.name, obj.age` instead of `this`. Otherwise you have to bind function to object `greet.bind(p1)`

Comment: @JózefPodlecki this will not work because obj is of type `T`, it doesn't know about `name` and `age`.

Comment: @Jozef, When I use ```obj```  instead of  ```this```, I get following compiler errors 
1) Property 'name' does not exist on type 'T'
2) Property 'age' does not exist on type 'T'.  But get expected output (when TS converts code into JS)

When I remove ```obj``` and use ```this``` instead, I DON'T get any compilation error.

Comment: I'll use different type of object and see how Generics work in TS. I am beginner in TS and learning on my own. I have definite done some mistakes here but can't figure it out. So I hope some senior/expert can show me my mistakes and correct me. 

so, what's the point of generic in this case ---   just learning and clearing my understanding :)

Comment: Using generics in this case doesn't make much sense. If `obj` is generic, the function `greet` doesn't know it has the property `name` and `age`. That's why you get compilation errors when you use `this.name` and `this.age` (even if it will run correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript just adds a static type system to JavaScript.  In JavaScript, your `greet()` function takes a parameter named `obj` and then completely ignores it; instead you're using [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), whose value is unlikely to be anything useful to you.  So you need to use `obj` instead of `this`, as the other answers correctly point out.

It was also pointed out that you don't seem to need generics here.  You can just make `obj` of the concrete type `{name: string, age: number}` and it will work:

```
function greet(obj: { name: string, age: number }) {
  console.log(`Hello, my name is ${obj.name}, I am ${obj.age} years old.`);
}
```

And `greet()` will work with `p1`:

```
greet(p1); // okay
```

but complain if you call it with something that is not assignable to the required type:

```
greet({ name: "the ageless one" }) // error, age is missing
```

and also if you pass in an object literal with excess properties, due to [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks):

```
greet({ name: "one-eyed jack", age: 45, eyes: 1 }) // excess property warning,
// eyes not expected
```

---

If you *really* want to use generics for this function, you should probably use a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) on your type parameter `T`, so that the compiler knows that it will have a string-valued `name` and a numeric-valued `age` property:

```
function greet<T extends { name: string, age: number }>(obj: T) {
  console.log(`Hello, my name is ${obj.name}, I am ${obj.age} years old.`);
}
```

So `T` is still not known exactly inside the implementation of `greet()`, but we know it has to be some subtype of `{name: string, age: number}`, and so now there's no compiler error when we read the `name` and `age` properties of `obj`.

Calling `greet(p1)` works because `p1` meets the constraint:

```
greet(p1); // okay
```

And, as before, if you pass in something that doesn't meet the constraint you get an error:

```
greet({ name: "the ageless one" }) // error, age is missing
```

Finally, if you pass in something more specific than the constraint such as an extra property, there will be no error, and `T` will be inferred as the more specific type:

```
greet({ name: "one-eyed jack", age: 45, eyes: 1 }) // okay,
// T is inferred as {name: string, age: number, eyes: number}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBhA9seAnCAXZA3gLABQSSANnkjAIxIC8SBSokAXEgERT4BuELgBokIAOYROAViQBfANylS5AGYBXTLgCWGJGJx4AFGgBGAK04s2kpLyxbgYkeJvA1YExCxyAlM2XkSPAYUGhUAHQUaGKGAAYAEhAUUSJgAJ6s4MhaUEgAJASmZuHWsiIAkqJg+YXm4S6ySGkQIFi5YQAm4bE+8kgBskpkega4hnS9SAD0U0hoANYgaUPk+hBGVlmcXLgAFsguVFDtwIK+07NeWGhYzhJIOUhgOVAOYisj62ObHNwYEABaCDNDpIMwIebCUQSTgAFikImB0E49FkfhmSAgAA9EMcaNcYF5cBkAO6tYBvIQBDFI3LANC4TFYwnwfAdIaDEjWWAIZAAcQgp3s8H8wyojLojGYmV+PH4gjuNhkCg+6k0OmAnzwAB4ACpM-DADq5H42OyU6GudyebyyAB8xnMnF1fmIw3IwWAoQiURiCSSKSeGWsD1yBSKJSyZSQlXANQjDSaLTacwoXR6imGnICayMEz6GIWSw+ue+MpsO32lqOJzOaIumKw11ultDTxebxLo0Mpu2-yBILBEKhLjhCMxzSgKPOhcWaSpwwx+seDhUVwgoJAJusnHNjkVnDcHi8iMnh+tXk5siAA)

Comment: Hi, @jcalz, It really helped me a lot and cleared my understanding. I really thank you for taking your time out and explaining me about my mistakes. I had understanding that  this(keyword)==object in JS.  I was thinking that if I pass object as parameter into function, this (keyword) will eventually replace with actual object and I can use properties of that object inside the function , hence I was using this (keyword). Just like we use this(keyword) in Call method. Would you mind telling me bit more about this (keyword) briefly and how/when I can use that in function, please?

Answer (score 3):

You are receiving `undefined` because `this.name` and `this.age` do not reference the object that you passed to the function, instead they reference properties in scope, which are apparently undefined.

Based on the code you provided, there is no reason why your function should be generic. You're not using it as a generic function either.

First, you should define an interface for your variable `p1`. You're using typescript, which allows for compile time type safety.

```
interface Person {
name: string;
age: number;
}
```

Now you can use this interface to initialize your variable

```
const p1: Person = {name: "steve", age: 5};
```

This will enforce that `p1` is of type `Person`. It is also constant, which only means that you can't reassign to p1, you can still change it's properties though.

Again, your function does not need to be generic, but you should provide a type to the parameter, so your function knows what it's dealing with.

```
function greet(a_oPerson: Person): void {
  console.log(`Hello, my name is ${a_oPerson.name}, I am ${a_oPerson.age} years old.`);
}
```

Lastly, you should name your parameters accordingly, and also provide a return type, which you can do with typescript (even if it's just void).

Full example:

```
interface Person {
name: string;
age: number;
}

const p1: Person = {name: "steve", age: 5};

function greet(a_oPerson: Person): void {

  console.log(`Hello, my name is ${a_oPerson.name}, I am ${a_oPerson.age} years old.`);
}

greet(p1);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can't do what @Mik suggests another option is type guard

```
interface CertainObjectType {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

let p1 = {name: "steve", age: 5};

function isCertainObjectType(obj: any): obj is CertainObjectType {
    return obj.name !== undefined;
}

function greet<T> (obj: T) {
    if(isCertainObjectType(obj)) {
        console.log(`Hello, my name is ${obj.name}, I am ${obj.age} years old.`);
    }
}

greet(p1);

function greet1<T>(this: T) {

    if(isCertainObjectType(this)) {
        console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}, I am ${this.age} years old.`);
    }
}

greet1.bind(this)();
```